# Three.js glow shader front face not rendering in chrome, works in other browsers

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, three.js, webgl

I am running into an issue where I am trying to apply a custom shader material to a series of  nested objects to simulate a glow effect around each node.  The effect works well on my home laptop (windows 8.1 latest chrome), but my work computer does not render the frontface of the glowing object, only the backface.  I have checked it against a few systems and it seems to be mostly a chrome rendering issue on windows devices.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/gjcgv.gif

I have included a codepen example where I shifted the glow off to the side and you can see that in some versions it is not rendering the front group of normals. The red dots should have a glow applied to each of them that shows up on the front and back(left and right in example). Any help would be appreciated, I am stumped as to what is going on.

```
Here is the shader material settings
local.glowNodeMat = new THREE.ShaderMaterial( 
        {
            uniforms: 
            { 
                "c":   { type: "f", value: 0 },
                "p":   { type: "f", value: 5.5 },
                glowColor: { type: "c", value: new THREE.Color(0xaaccff) },
                viewVector: { type: "v3", value: local.camera.position }
            },
            vertexShader:   document.getElementById( 'vertexShader'   ).textContent,
            fragmentShader: document.getElementById( 'fragmentShader' ).textContent,
            side: THREE.FrontSide,
            blending: THREE.AdditiveBlending,
            transparent: true
        });
```

http://codepen.io/sniejadlik/pen/oDarE

///////////////////
FIXED thanks to Volune.  Thanks for the help!

Fixed Vertex shader

```
<script id="vertexShader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
    uniform vec3 viewVector;
    uniform float c;
    uniform float p;
    varying float intensity;
    void main() 
    {
        vec3 vNormal = normalize( normalMatrix * normal );
        vec3 vNormel = normalize( normalMatrix * viewVector );
        // incorrect intensity = pow( c - dot(vNormal, vNormel), p );
        intensity = pow( abs(c - dot(vNormal, vNormel) ), p );

        gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );
    }
    </script>

    <!-- fragment shader a.k.a. pixel shader -->
    <script id="fragmentShader" type="x-shader/x-vertex"> 
    uniform vec3 glowColor;
    varying float intensity;
    void main() 
    {
        vec3 glow = glowColor * intensity;
        gl_FragColor = vec4( glow, 1.0 );
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in your vertex shader:

```
intensity = pow( c - dot(vNormal, vNormel), p );
```

You have `c = 0` and `p = 0.5`. `c - dot(vNormal, vNormel)` may be negative (when the dot product returns a positive value), so you're trying to get the square of a negative value.

For some unknown reason, the fallback in Firefox looks like `pow( abs(...), 0.5 )`, while the fallback in Chrome seems to be `0.0`.

Try to fix your shader like this:

```
intensity = pow( abs( c - dot(vNormal, vNormel) ), p );
```

Comment: @scott-niejadlik If you confirm that's the solution, please copy the vertex shader in your question for Q+A clarity.

Comment: Thanks so much!  That solved it, I will definitely have to remember this in the future, I would have spent way longer trying to solve it.  Thanks!